# RuntimeError: "reflection_pad2d" not implemented for 'Byte'

Tags: python, pytorch

```py
padding = (2, 2, 2, 2)
img = torch.nn.functional.pad(img, padding, mode='reflect')
out = torch.nn.functional.conv2d(img, kernel, groups=img.shape[1])
```

Here is the complete Error:

```
  File "/home/amir/PycharmProjects/LPTN/loadPretrainedModel.py", line 57, in conv_gauss
    img = torch.nn.functional.pad(img, padding, mode='reflect')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py", line 4017, in _pad
    return torch._C._nn.reflection_pad2d(input, pad)
RuntimeError: "reflection_pad2d" not implemented for 'Byte'
```

What do you think is the problem? I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might need to change dtype of your `img` to float e.g. `img.float()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to change data type of your `img` to float e.g. `img.float()`. Many operations such as `reflection_pad2d` are implemented only for float tensors.